A question regarding spray foam installation on damp foundation walls
We're scheduled to have our cinder block foundation/crawlspace walls sprayed today, however we got some rain last night and there's a good chance that some of the wall surface will be slightly damp. We live in this house and are being told we can reoccupy the space 12h after installation. Will this dampness affect curing time and off gassing? We're trying to avoid exposure to isocyanate/VOCs. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Most of the expanding foams actually cure faster with moisture present.
